# How to add toggle button to title bar of custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application there is one button on click of that button I show custom dialog box

I create dialog like this:

```
  tempDialog = new Dialog(ConfigureActivity.this);
  tempDialog.setContentView(R.layout.tempreturedialog);
  tempDialog.setTitle("Change Temperature");
```

and layout of dialog is:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/roomTemp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/unit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/time"
                android:prompt="@string/Select" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
       >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/min"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Min : 0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/max"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Max : 100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Repeat"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/repeatafter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:entries="@array/repeat"
            android:prompt="@string/RepeatAfter" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Set" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I want to add toggle button near title of dialog so if toggle button is set to 'ON' show some contains in dialog and if 'OFF' some other contains

How can I do this??

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "near title of dialog". Where exactly are you trying to get this? Because you could just add this toggle button to the top of your layout and get "near" the title of the dialog.

Comment: I want toggle button on right side of title like we have in wifi setting screen

Answer (score 0):

Over here,

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

  tempDialog = new Dialog(ConfigureActivity.this);
  tempDialog.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tempreturedialog, null));
  tempDialog.setTitle("Change Temperature");
```

Comment: Giving error to tempDialog.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tempreturedialog));The method inflate(int, ViewGroup) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout add a row at the top with a textview and toggle button. Then don't set the title on the dialog but instead set it in the text view, leaving that upper space empty. You will simulate a title with a toggle button next to it.